# Keyerror while formatting python multi line string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-formatting

Can anybody help me with the error I am getting upon calling the below function. Looks line an issue where it is not able to properly format the multiline graphQL String:

```
def verify_obs():
    question_list = ["baae592c-ec9e-11e3-99de-021505f49f8a","37b5556a-b229-4010-8920-6fc72e5f629e","df3c569b-3bb7-4376-8c33-7f20603a2790","a6bfd272-aad0-4e5d-9a5e-c4a1268ea4ba","e1e9ca6a-4ceb-476e-a87c-7d591486c8da"]

    my_query = '''query {
  willObfuscateQuestions (questionIdList: {0}) {
    questionId
    state
    examId
    endTime
    startTime
  }
}'''.format(question_list)

    ds_response = requests.post(
        url='<end point here>',
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        json={'query': my_query}
    )
    response_list = ds_response.json()['data']['willObfuscateQuestions']
    print(response_list)
    for item in response_list:
        state = item['state']
        if state == 'Obfuscated' and int(ds_response.status_code) == 200:
            print('Question is obfuscated')
            return 0
        else:
            raise Exception('Obfuscation failed with response - ', ds_response.json())
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ubhatia/Documents/RFSetup/karma-moderation-pipeline/robot-tests/KarmaModeration/Config/methods.py", line 198, in <module>
    print(verify_obs())
  File "/Users/ubhatia/Documents/RFSetup/karma-moderation-pipeline/robot-tests/KarmaModeration/Config/methods.py", line 49, in verify_obs
    }'''.format(question_list)
KeyError: '\n  willObfuscateQuestions (questionIdList'
```

Comment: What should the identifiers in braces in the format template string ("questionId", "state", "examId", ...) do or mean?

Comment: they are values to be fetched from graphQL endpoint